# Making a generic container typemap and accessing the template argument

Tags: c++, swig

Let's say I want to create a generic `std::vector<T>*` typemap. SWIG can do this if I do not specify any template argument.

Then I can access the full type, including its template argument by using `$ltype`:

```
%typemap(in) std::vector * ($*ltype obj) {
  // allocating on the heap
  $1 = new $ltype;

  // allocating on the stack
  $1 = &obj;
}
```

Does anyone see any way I could access the template argument type and especially its descriptor, something along the lines of `$descriptor(arg($ltype))`?

Comment: Does the `value_type` type alias work, as in `$descriptor($ltype::value_type)`?